# Not allowing a user to move forward to logging in until given access

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, forms, permissions

I am trying to figure out how to deny a user access from signing in to my site unless they have been approved. I am making my site private to only those I allow to join. Anyone can register, but once they do they are given a permission/group level of 1 or 'bench'. Once I accept the user and change the permission level, then they are able to login.

As of now, I am stopping the level/group 1 users with a redirect back to the index page(where they sign in at). However, I want to not allow them to move forward to the next page at all. The reason being is I want to display some sort of pop up alert displaying a message that I created.

I'm not sure if I can do this with validation or the way I am trying to do it. I added on to my login code and am attempting to put my permission code I had on the signed in page to try to stop it from the start. Basically, in an attempt that if the user tries to log in, the script dies once it sees that the permission level is at the group 'bench'. Then a pop alert displays saying why.

I'm not having much success with it. My group/permission levels have a name and ID. I have tried putting both in this single quotatiob's like 'bench' and '1', but I get the same error with both.

Fatal error: Call to a member function hasPermission() on a non-object in /home4/pfarley1/public_html/example.com/index.php on line 12

I'm trying to log them in like this...

```
<?php
if(Input::exists()) {
if(Token::check(Input::get('token'))) {

    $validate = new Validate();
    $validation = $validate->check($_POST, array(
        'username' => array('required' => true),
        'password' => array('required' => true)
    ));
// added this line in
if($user->hasPermission('1')) {
        die($permissionError);}
    if($validation->passed()) {
        $user = new User();

        $remember = (Input::get('remember') === 'on') ? true : false;
        $login = $user->login(Input::get('username'), Input::get('password'), $remember);

        if($login) {
            Redirect::to('userIndex.php');
        } else {
            $tryagain = '<span class="signinpanel">' . "The information you entered did not match our records." . '</span>';
        }

    } else {
        foreach($validation->errors() as $error) {
            echo $error, '<br>';
        }
    }
}
}
?>
```

My permission code for users..

```
public function hasPermission($key) {
$group = $this->_db->get('groups', array('id', '=', $this->data()->group));

 if($group->count()) {
        $permissions = json_decode($group->first()->permissions, true);

        if($permissions[$key] == true) {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

What am I doing wrong this this or is there a better way to do this?

Edit:
The last question wasn't specific enough, so I added info and there has been modification to the code in how I was trying to do this.

Comment: Glad someone is paying attention :) props jeroen.

Comment: The last question wasn't specific enough, so I added info and there has been modification to the code in how I was trying to do this.

Comment: You should add that to the original question, not ask a new one.

Comment: Even in your marked as duplicate message it says "or ask a new question". That's what I did. The question wasn't close enough and I brought up new points.

Comment: Plus it never had an answer for it.

Answer (score 0):

What is `$user` on line 12?

```
if($user->hasPermission('1')) {
```

Error message is pretty explicit.

Comment: That is part of my user class that I have required on the page.